PHPStorm Перестали работать подсказки css в blade
После обновления до PHPSTORM 2024.1 перестали работать подсказки css в balde файлах.
Когда ради эксперемента измненяю на .html все рабоатет как часы. Немогу победить, помогите

Связался с поддержкой PHPStorm у них баг в 2024.1 версии. Обязуются исправить в обновлениях

Был баг у phpStorm поправили с обновлением, теперь все вновь работает
